# Can I zoom out windows or scale the whole desktop?

Tags: window, xrandr

I have a 17" laptop with 1600x900 resolution, but it's not enough to open windows side by side. I'm wondering if i could zoom out (or any other solution) windows (or the whole desktop). Is there a solution on xserver or on the WM to make this happen?

By the way, compiz zoom out plugin don't let you to zoom out more than 1:1 which is not enough, I want to zoom out more the same way as spreading all windows with unity-tweak-tool.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Disclaimer: I do not know if it works for all graphic drivers. Intel driver here, in 13.04.

First of all get the normal screen you have active:

```
xrandr --current
```

My output is:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1024 x 600, maximum 32767 x 32767
LVDS1 connected 1024x600+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 220mm x 129mm
   1024x600       60.0*+   65.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Ok, it is `LVDS1`. Now for example to zoom out at half linear dimension:

```
xrandr --output LVDS1 --scale 2x2
```

The whole screen should zoom out. Now I have:

```
(0)asus-romano:~/research/reviews% xrandr --current
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 2048 x 1200, maximum 32767 x 32767
LVDS1 connected 2048x1200+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 220mm x 129mm
   1024x600       60.0*+   65.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

So the systems thinks it has a 2048x1200 screen. Very useful for crappy programs that thinks you have a gazillion pixel space and do not offer scrollbars in some option windows...

To go back:

```
xrandr --output LVDS1 --scale 1x1
```

(You can use 1.5x1.5, too). Look at `man xrandr` for a lot of fancy things.

Oops. There seem to be a bug in which the extended video zone is not reachable: 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/883319 and upstream https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=39949

A workaround for this is to specify the desired larger area as a `--panning` option, e.g.:

```
 xrandr --output LVDS1 --scale 2x2 --panning 2048x1200
```

It will not cause any actual panning, since the whole large area fits on the screen due to the scaling.

Comment: it almost works OK, but i need to move the cursor around.i know that my screen specification can't do more than that. but, I'm searching for a solution to bypass them by removing some pixels from the frame the same way when zooming out photos so i can see the whole desktop on my screen

Comment: Yep --- I see. The zone where the mouse can go is limited to the original desktop (strange). Maybe is time for another question...

Comment: OK --- seems a bug. I linked the two most probable culprits.

Comment: "First of all get the normal screen you have active: " ­— uh, how? :-)

Comment: @ChristopherDone: ok, missing the `xrandr`  line.

Comment: I believe `xrandr` is using bilinear scaleing as default. Can someone comfirm?

Comment: I do not know why I can't edit this answer. Anyway ---- there is a workaround for the bug in https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/883319/comments/121

Comment: *`xrandr --output LVDS1 --scale 2x2` The whole screen should zoom out.* - FWIW, for me, on Ubuntu 18.04.4 running Cinnamon with NVIDIA 430.50 drivers, and a monitor attached via HDMI, it doesn't. The framebuffer gets 4x bigger, but the monitor only shows the top left quarter.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option of scaling out the desktop upto 1:4 and scaling in upto 1:0.5. This option is available in **System settings -> Display**. However, this is not in a very good shape at the moment, have seen issues where [it breaks unity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/440958/scaling-ubuntu-14-04-ui-problem/440967#440967).

So this is recommended only if its absolutely necessary and other solutions don't work out.