# Is there any way to set the display scaling back to default other than from the display settings dialog?

Tags: display, dpi, scaling

I scaled the UI from the display menu. Now it is way too big and I can't get to the slider to reset it.

Any ideas how I can change the scaling in Unity back to default without accessing the settings menu??

I tried

```
dconf reset -f /org/unity
```

with no luck.

Comment: wtf man? This command will reset the whole unity setting that means all customization of the unity env!

Answer (score 12):

The problem seems to be that you are not able to see/control the lower part of the "Display settings". There is a workaround to move the lower part on top. For this, go to **System settings -> Display** and then right-click on the window bar on top and click on "Move". Do not move your mouse after clicking on "Move", otherwise the keyboard is not used for moving, only the mouse has the control for moving the window.

[image: right click to move]

and then use your keyboard to move the window to top, slowing showing you the lower part where you drag your mouse to reset the scale to 1. Remember to click "Apply" for the settings to persist and then click on "Keep this configuration".

You can also hold down the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key and then click on any area of the window to move it up until you can see the slider.

Answer (score 6):

In Ubuntu GNOME (and I assume for other distros running vanilla GNOME3), I found that scaling the desktop and windows with

`gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings overrides "[{'Gdk/WindowScalingFactor', <2>}]"`

in conjunction with the already mentioned

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface scaling-factor 2`.

leas to more consistent results than just the latter.

This is also the setting that is affected when you change the "Windows / HiDPI / Window Scaling" value in `gnome-tweak-tool`. For future reference, I found the command [on the Hi-DPI page in the GNOME Wiki](https://wiki.gnome.org/HowDoI/HiDpi).

Answer (score 3):

This also worked for me:

```
gsettings set com.ubuntu.user-interface scale-factor "{'eDP1': 10}"
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.interface scaling-factor # same as '1.0'
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Interface text-scale-factor 1.25
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor 1.25
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if the scaling uses the `xrandr` mechanism. If yes, issue in the terminal:

```
xrandr --output LVDS1 --scale 1x1
```

substituting LSVD1 with the name of your active display obtained by running `xrandr --current`.

[More info in this other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/379132/16395).

Answer (score 1):

1st of all find that which monitor/display(If you have connected with two or more monitors in case) do you need to scale and **it's name** according to your machine ?

Using command

```
xrandr
```

you will get all informations about your display/monitors. here is mine :

[image]

As you are seeing i have connected two monitors and i want to scale my 2nd monitor which is connceted through hdmi and it's called **HDMI-1-1**.

So to scale i have to use

```
xrandr --output HDMI-1-1 --scale 1x1
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
gsettings set com.ubuntu.user-interface scale-factor "{'eDP1': 10}"
```

There is also this:

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.interface scaling-factor # same as '1.0'
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Interface text-scale-factor 1.25
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor 1.25
```

I've found these in https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1310316.

Answer (score 0):

This rescued me so I can once again use the Displays control panel:

```
gsettings reset com.ubuntu.user-interface scale-factor
```

Answer (score -1):

This worked on Debian:

1.Click on Activities

2.Search "Tweak Tool"

3.In Tweak Tool search bar, search for "Window scaling", Drag the window till the "-" sign appears and decrease it.

[search for windows scaling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyvMS.png)

[Drag the window and decrease scaling value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9zKd.png)