# Display became too big for the screen after upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: display, screen

On Ubuntu 16.04 the display has become to big for the screen

This seems not to be adjustable from settings (lower or higher resolution 9:6 - still keeps overscreen.)

"Monitor setting" from Ubuntu Software can make it smaller, but it distorts the proportions making the display too wide

Changing monitors and playing with the monitor's resolution didn't help.

On Ubuntu 14.04 I had old software for Radeon v/cards that was OK on resolution 1750x.... (but now no choice of software) I cannot see the clock or icons.

Comment: If someone still have this type of problem then (s)he can have a look on my answer there [Is there any way to set the display scaling back to default other than from the display settings dialog?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/440958/is-there-any-way-to-set-the-display-scaling-back-to-default-other-than-from-the/1259347#1259347)

Answer (score 1):

I'm a complete noob when it comes to Ubuntu but after 2 weeks of troubleshooting using `xrandr`, `nvidia-settings`, and dozens of `.conf` files I found out that a program named Bumblebee was blacklisting Nvidia drivers in the `bumblebee.conf`.

All I did was type in `sudo apt-get purge bumblebee` and as I was expecting a black screen again, it loaded in full resolution.

EDIT: If the screen freezes then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and type in your login credentials in the black screen and type in `reboot`

I found my solution here: [Trying to figure out what happened with lightdm and Xorg](https://askubuntu.com/a/690103/578581)

Answer (score 1):

I fixed my problem of display too large for screen by going into the menu of my tv which I use as a monitor and in the Picture button menu chose Size then Just Scan and voila! the display shrank to fit.