# how can i increase the screen resolution ubuntu 15.10?

Tags: nvidia, screen, display-resolution

i installed ubuntu 15.10 and i have NVIDIA geforce 920m 4g
but my masximum screen resolution is 1366 * 768
, how can i increase the resolution to the maximum that can the NVIDIA handle ?

[image]

Comment: Have you added the NVIDIA drivers?

Comment: @CharlesGreen yes i installed the driver

Comment: What is the physical resolution of the LCD panel? Most laptops are 1366 * 768 --- and from the screenshot I deduce you are on a laptop (battery gauge...). You do not gain anything by going to more resolution than the physical one, although you can scale the display with `xrandr`: http://askubuntu.com/questions/379123/can-i-zoom-out-windows-or-scale-the-whole-desktop

Comment: @Rmano
iam using dell inspiron 15 5000 (15.6)

Comment: but i am using a good VGA how i cannot increase the resolution ?

Comment: Your laptop's resolution is 1366x768. You can't just magically increase the amount of pixels it has but, like Rmano said, you can use `xrandr` to scale your display, which means two or three pixels of the signal will be compressed into one physical one. It looks horrible, though, and I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: How is the external monitor connected? Which kind of monitor? If it is not automatically detected, there is a bit of work to do: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xrandr#Adding_undetected_resolutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The display can only display so much.  Otherwise you're wasting time and energy rendering pixels the display can't show.  Your card is running at the maximum resolution of this display already.

If you were to increase the resolution, you would likely get a distorted display.

In other words, if you CAN do this you don't want to.  99.9% of the time, the resolution options given in the settings are the ones you monitor can handle.  If it's a second display that you're trying to use, then you may be set to clone displays.

Comment: thank you for your answer, please tell is my driver installed true from the screen shot ?

Comment: Yes it looks like it