# How do I shrink my monitor's size?

Tags: display, intel-graphics, monitor, xrandr

I would like a black, empty margin surrounding my entire screen, effectively turning a 24" monitor into a 20" one instead.

My setup:

- Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
- Intel Graphics
- Xfce4 (I'd prefer a cross desktop enviroment solution)

Having tried `xrandr` with a combination of many different parameters, including: `--scale`, `--panning`, etc. I cannot shrink my monitor as desired.

If shrinking my monitor isn't possible with `xrandr`, `fbset` or some other tool, does an option  to add in my `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf` file exist?

Comment: What happens when you run `xrandr` with the `--scale` option? Did you specify which output, did it display an error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I zoom out windows or scale the whole desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/379123/can-i-zoom-out-windows-or-scale-the-whole-desktop)

Comment: `--scale 2x2` doubles the screen resolution, `--scale 0.5x0.5` does nothing.

Comment: What about `xrandr -s 100x100` or similar?

Comment: I have seen that thread many times, but nothing there works.

Comment: That just changes the screen resolution, still filling up the entire monitor.

Comment: Good point, my mistake. Try this method to set the display size and position/size separately: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/337537/how-to-change-resolution-of-one-screen-so-that-only-part-of-it-is-used

Comment: If your monitor is 1920x1080 physical pixels and you want 10% smaller with borders you want to change it to 1800x900 active pixels with rest black?

Comment: I tried the mentioned method and, although I can reduce the monitor size, I can't position it and everything flickers in the unused area.

Comment: Yes, WinEunuuchs2Unix, that is what I want.  Well, I'd like to experiment with the "10%" figure.

Comment: @charlie Are you saying that `--pos` makes the unused area flicker?

Comment: The unused area keeps flickering between black (blank) and what used to be there before (another window, desktop, etc.).

Comment: Other than the flicker and unable to center (`--pos` does nothing), this is the closest I got: `xrandr --output HDMI1 --scale 1.1x1.1 && xrandr -s 1920x1080`  `xrandr -s` needs to be a separate command, otherwise, the mouse enters the unused area.

Answer (score 1):

> ...effectively turning a 24" monitor into a 20" one...

That is surprisingly easy to achieve (replace `DVI-0` with your monitor, of course):

```
xrandr --output DVI-0 --set "underscan hborder" 128 --set "underscan vborder" 128
```

...and turn it on/off using:

```
xrandr --output DVI-0 --set underscan on
xrandr --output DVI-0 --set underscan off
```

On a 24" monitor, the image should shrink down to about 20.2".

The borders have to be values in the range 0-128, where 1 results in the smallest borders, 128 in the largest, and 0 is somewhere in between. I don't know what these values actually represent.

Comment: `charlie:~$ xrandr --output HDMI1 --set "underscan hborder" 128 --set "underscan vborder" 128
X Error of failed request:  BadName (named color or font does not exist)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  11 (RRQueryOutputProperty)
  Serial number of failed request:  43
  Current serial number in output stream:  43`

Comment: Please look at the output of ``xrandr --verbose``, maybe your monitor doesn't support underscan, but I tested it with a really old monitor, so I doubt it. Try enabling underscan first, before setting the borders. It may be helpful to add the output of `xrandr --verbose ` to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you would want to do this, it might even cause burn-in problems depending on your monitor, but instead of changing the display (xrandr) resolution/display/pixels, try this:

- Make some new **XFCE panels on the top, sides, and bottom, with a solid black colour** (in the Appearance tab) and options like this in the Display tab (changing the Row Size to however thick you prefer):

  [image]

  Maximized windows will not cover the panels, and you could even use one side as an extra-large status / window panel (if your desktop is like that, similar to XFCE's defaults). I'm pretty sure every desktop has some sort of panels that should work similarly.

Comment: This wouldn't trap the mouse within the desired area, nor alter full screen windows such as YouTube.

Comment: XFCE's Settings -> Workspaces -> Margins tab stops maximized windows (similar to the panels), but not full-screen browsers and probably not youtube either... strange that it doesn't

Comment: Yeah, those margin settings are for normal computer usage (I'm happy with a full display for that), I just find full screen videos too big when I'm tired.