# how can i literally shrink the size of one of my monitors?

Tags: multiple-monitors, xrandr

I saw a question very similar to this, ["how do I shrink my monitor's size?"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1079384/how-do-i-shrink-my-monitors-size) wherein the asker requests a black margin surrounding their screen; how would I achieve the same thing on Wayland? since tools like Xrandr seemingly don't work with Wayland, anyways.
edit: sorry, I was unsure how much information I needed to provide. I hope this is enough; I am connected via HDMI to my target monitor (display port on the main one), ubuntu 22.04, I have an AMD ryzen 5 5600/radeon 6600 XT.

Comment: Not enough info to answer. What version of Ubuntu? What desktop? What PC? What graphics card? What device driver for it? What screen(s)? Connected how, via what kind of cables and what kind of ports?

Comment: I edited the post and added more info, sorry about that. also, what do you mean by what desktop? like the specs? or GNOME?